# Android - RecyclerView multiplies itself every time device is rotated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a landscape configuration for one of my app's activities. This activity contains a fragment and this fragment contains one textview and one recyclerview. Everytime when i switch in between portrait and landscape modes, the recyclerview leaves the view of itself like however it was before i turned the device. It might be a little difficult to understand what i try to ask here, so i recorded a gif for that.

https://giphy.com/gifs/3Wv7NAtT8ezP1SQhDu

This is my activity

```
public class RecipeStepsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static Recipe recipe;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_steps);

    if (StepDetailActivity.SDA_TAG.equals(StepDetailActivity.NEGATIVE))
        recipe = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("recipe");
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("recipe", recipe);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null)
        ab.setTitle(recipe.getName());

    RecipeStepsFragment recipeStepsFragment = new RecipeStepsFragment();
    recipeStepsFragment.setArguments(b);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout_steps, recipeStepsFragment).commit();
}
```

}

This is my fragment

```
public class RecipeStepsFragment extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.recipe_steps_rv)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
@BindView(R.id.ingredients_tv)
TextView tv_ingredients;
List<Step> steps;
public RecipeStepsFragment(){}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_steps, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    List<Ingredients> ingredients;
    Recipe recipe = getArguments().getParcelable("recipe");
    steps = recipe.getSteps();
    initRecyclerView();

    ingredients = recipe.getIngredients();
    String ingredientsAppended = "INGREDIENTS" + "\n\n";
    if (ingredients == null){
        ingredientsAppended = "Not Available";
    } else {
        for (int a = 0 ; a < ingredients.size() ; a++) {
            Ingredients i = ingredients.get(a);
            ingredientsAppended += String.valueOf(i.getQuantity()) + " " +
                    i.getMeasure() + " " +
                    i.getIngredient();
            if (a+1 != ingredients.size()){
                ingredientsAppended += '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    tv_ingredients.setText(ingredientsAppended);
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt("position"));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("position", recyclerView.getVerticalScrollbarPosition());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void initRecyclerView(){
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    RecipeStepsRecyclerAdapter recipeStepsRecyclerAdapter =
            new RecipeStepsRecyclerAdapter(steps, new RecipeStepsRecyclerAdapter.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(int clickedItemPosition) {
                    Intent intentToStepDetail = new Intent(getActivity(), StepDetailActivity.class);
                    Step step = steps.get(clickedItemPosition);
                    intentToStepDetail.putExtra("step", step);
                    startActivity(intentToStepDetail);
                }
            }, getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recipeStepsRecyclerAdapter);
    recipeStepsRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

This is my adapter

```
public class RecipeStepsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeStepsRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Step> stepList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
final private ClickListener clickListener;

public RecipeStepsRecyclerAdapter(List<Step> stepList, ClickListener clickListener, Context context){
    this.stepList = stepList;
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipe_steps_recyclerview_adapter, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Step step = stepList.get(position);
    String stepContent = step.getShortDescription();
    holder.listingNumber.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
    holder.stepContent.setText(stepContent);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return stepList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView listingNumber;
    TextView stepContent;

    private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        listingNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_number_tv);
        stepContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.step_content_tv);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        clickListener.onItemClick(clickedPosition);
    }
}

public interface ClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int clickedItemPosition);
}
```

}

Layout files are as I already explained above. I guess nothing special to post here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you add a **new** fragment to the `Activity` every time it is created. Here's the end of your `onCreate(...)`:

```
RecipeStepsFragment recipeStepsFragment = new RecipeStepsFragment();
recipeStepsFragment.setArguments(b);
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout_steps, recipeStepsFragment).commit();
```

The `FragmentManager` keeps a reference to the fragment you add to it even if the host `Activity` is destroyed. Thus, you keep adding new instances of the `RecipeStepsFragment` eventually overlaying each other and producing the seen behavior.

Don't worry, the fix is pretty simple: use [`replace(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment)) instead of [`add(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction#add(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment)):

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_steps, recipeStepsFragment).commit();
```

---

*P.S.: Note, however, that replacing the current fragment with a new one every time the host activity is destroyed is not a good idea. You should check either if the `savedInstanceState` is `null` (which indicates that it's a non-recreated `Activity`) or if the given fragment is already added (define a tag when adding the fragment and try finding it in `onCreate(...)` before replacing the old one).*

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change the rotation of the screen your **activity is destroyed and recreated.** That is the reason why your list is populating with new items each time when you switch between your orientation.

So it's important you only instantiate your objects once, and not keep recreating them each time your app is recreated. Which then adds them to your list.

You can use [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).

If you want your app to allow orientation change, apply logic so your list don't get new items each time when activity is created.

Answer (score 0):

Put configChanges attribute in your activity in menifest file

```
<activity android:name=".VideoActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```